# "Which one to read first (a) or (b)?" or "Which one should I read first(a) or (b)?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

I'm confused between these two sentences. Which one's correct ?

Comment: The first one is not a complete sentence.

Comment: What are you trying to say?  Are you trying to form a question?  It would help if we had more context.

Comment: The second sentence is asking for advice. The first sentence is incorrect

Comment: And what the first one is asking for @user178049

Comment: @ArdisEll The first sentence is incorrect.

Comment: Even after editing ?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question.  Yes, the first one is still incorrect, although you will sometimes hear people use it informally.  The second one is correct (although you should really have a comma in there: "Which one should I read first, A or B?")

Comment: Yeah, that's what confuses me. People use 1st sentence too @stangdon

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking someone for an opinion, the second is unambiguous - it conveys that you are indecisive and asks for input.

The first could be taken as a rhetorical, in the same way that "what to do" can be used to convey your indecision without necessarily seeking suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct however, their meanings are *slightly* different.

**"Which one to read first"** - It means that one is asking the other that which  thing he is supposed to read first? Consider a man who has a servant. He asked his servant to bring a newspaper and read it to him. His servant brings the newspaper however, he doesn't know which news should he tell his master first. So, here he would ask his master, "which one to read first"?

**"Which one should I read first"** - Here, he basically is asking that what do you suggest reading first.

Comment: The difference is still unclear to me :/